# QGIS - hide layer objects that are not filtered by atlas

Tags: qgis, layouts, atlas

I have a polygon layer with f.e. 500 parcels including their owner information. Using the atlas function, I'd like to print the parcels sorted by owner. Using the atlas, I can select the layer containing the poylgons as coverage layer, select pagename "owner" and it's almost what i need. But how can I set an automatic filter, to hide all the parcels from that layer which are not in the focus of the atlas page, not the owners? something like inverting the "hidden coverage layer"...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way is to set a Rule based styling with two rules:

1. `@atlas_featureid = $id` Which will show the current atlas feature. Lets say I want a brown symbol.
2. ELSE, and set the Opacity to 0 %.

I've set it to 20 % just to be able to show you there are more features:
[image]

[image]

Comment: is there a way to add this to an already existing rule like "usage" = 'road' and secondly "usage = 'forrest'? Because my layer is alreafy rule based, and i am not cetrain how to add this...

Comment: Yes, combine the conditions with `AND` or `OR` [operators](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_and_or.asp)